# How to get the open and close from this JSON request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, alpha-vantage

There is an api called Alpha Vantage that gets real time stock data. By making a request it returns JSON. This is different to everything I have seen as it is not in an array. I can't get my head around it. I am using JQuery and Javascript and want to store the values in an array so that I can read them later.

Here is the format of the JSON. (The complete JSON)
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo

And here is a sample of that data:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-10-06 16:00:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2017-10-06 16:00:00": {
        "1. open": "75.9700",
        "2. high": "76.0000",
        "3. low": "75.9500",
        "4. close": "76.0000",
        "5. volume": "2277972"
    },
    "2017-10-06 15:59:00": {
        "1. open": "75.9700",
        "2. high": "75.9700",
        "3. low": "75.9500",
        "4. close": "75.9650",
        "5. volume": "142469"
    },
    "2017-10-06 15:58:00": {
        "1. open": "75.9700",
        "2. high": "75.9900",
        "3. low": "75.9500",
        "4. close": "75.9600",
        "5. volume": "141434"
    },
```

And it goes on until the end.

Appreciate any help getting this data into an array as I am stuck on this part of my project.

Comment: What do you want the array to look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's one GIANT object, not an array, treat it like that ;) What values you need out of it, and why would you change it into an array. You can work with the object even better than an array, only not with same functions.

Comment: is this a php question ?

Comment: @laruiss I basically just want to get the opening and close prices so I can use it later.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I don't mind using php or javascript

Comment: @DanteTheSmith Okay, if it is better to treat is like that I would rather go with that. I want to try and get the opening and close prices of the stock

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
function traverse(jsonObj) {
if( typeof jsonObj == "object" ) {
    for (var prop in jsonObj){
        // k is either an array index or object key
        console.log(jsonObj[prop]);
        traverse(prop);
    }
}
else {
    // jsonOb is a number or string
}

}
traverse(data["Time Series (1min)"]);
```

fgfg

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

**JS CODE**

```
storeToarray();
function storeToarray(){
  let ItemArray = [];
  if(Object.keys(data).length > 1){
  var keus = Object.keys(data)[1];
    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[keus]).length; i++){
      var keusVal = Object.keys(data[keus])[i];
      var open = Object.keys(data[keus][keusVal])[0];
      var close = Object.keys(data[keus][keusVal])[1];
      var low = Object.keys(data[keus][keusVal])[2];
      var volume = Object.keys(data[keus][keusVal])[3];
      var high = Object.keys(data[keus][keusVal])[4];

     ItemArray.push({"open":data[keus][keusVal][open],"high" :data[keus][keusVal][high] ,"low" : data[keus][keusVal][low],"close":data[keus][keusVal][close],"volume":data[keus][keusVal][volume]})
    }
  }
  console.log(ItemArray);
}
```

[Click here to see JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/kbjrurur/1/)